# How do I run a GitHub Webhook after my Github Action's Workflow has finished?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-api, github-actions

Currently my GitHub Webhook is set up to deploy my website every time a push on master branch occurs. Now, with GitHub Actions in place for CI, I want to run this Webhook only if my CI on GitHub succeeds.

Can I tell my GitHub Webhook to wait for GitHub's CI **or** shouldn't I use a Webhook anymore but manage this behavior in my GitHub workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A webhook is a listener which is trigger by a specific JSON payload.

You could:

- modify your listener to detect a different payload
- send that different payload from your GitHub Action

That way, your local deployment process will be called by your GitHub Action.
If that deployment was *not* a local one (meaning on your server instead of a server accessible from GitHub), there are [quite a list of GitHub Actions dedicated to Deploy a site](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#deployment). In that case, no need for a webhook.

Comment: Clarified for me that a Webhook could be simply implemented by a GitHub Action, couldn't it? Thanks for your response! :)

Comment: @RobinWieruch Yes, although GitHub Actions are still fairly new, accessible through a beta program only.

Comment: But the `secret` would be public in the Github action, if the repository is public with all its GitHub actions, wouldn't it? So anyone could trigger it maliciously. The repository's Webhook isn't public and so it's secret isn't public as well.

Comment: @RobinWieruch only someone with write access to a (public or private) repo would be able to read/write a secret: https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#creating-and-using-secrets-encrypted-variables.

Comment: Ah super cool! Didn’t know that you can add secrets there! Thanks for the clarification.